# How to check for underlying heterogeneity in regression?

Tags: regression

I am doing a cross-country regression with multiple observations per country (1 per year). My Panel model shows some quadratic relation between the dependent and the independent variable of interest, but its unsure whether this relation is due to a universal connection or underlying heterogeneity of countries in terms of country characteristics, e.g. the demographic or economic structure of the countries.

My key question is, are there tests to differ between universal interactions (one globally working mechanism of action) and an aggregate effect that is just driven by unobserved heterogeneity of the units of investigation?

Comment: Can you give some more details? Sample size (number of countries, and within countries), which other variables, ... ?

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.